# Passing custom parameters in paypal express checkout NVP

Tags: paypal, paypal-nvp

I'm trying to find a way to pass a custom parameter through paypal's express checkout using NVP.
I've tried using the deprecated PAYMENTREQUEST_n_CUSTOM, the supposedly not deprecated PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CUSTOM and the CUSTOM parameters but none of them worked.

The only ways I can see right now (which I'd rather not use) are:
1. use one of the other parameters that I'm not using (like shipping)
2. use the return url and add to it the parameter as a GET parameter
3. use sessions.

According to the error page my version is 92.0. 
And the rest of the parameters are:

```
$nvpstr="&SHIPPINGAMT=0&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONNAME0=test&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONAMOUNT0=0&REQCONFIRMSHIPPING=0&NOSHIPPING=1&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONISDEFAULT0=true&ADDRESSOVERRIDE=1$shiptoAddress&".
               "&ALLOWNOTE=0&CUSTOM=".$CUSTOM.
               "&L_NAME0=".$L_NAME0."&L_AMT0=".$L_AMT0."&L_QTY0=".$L_QTY0.
               "&MAXAMT=".(string)$maxamt."&AMT=".(string)$amt."&ITEMAMT=".(string)$itemamt.
               "&CALLBACKTIMEOUT=4&CALLBACK=https://www.ppcallback.com/callback.pl&ReturnUrl=".$returnURL."&CANCELURL=".$cancelURL .
               "&CURRENCYCODE=".$currencyCodeType."&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=".$paymentType;
```

Comment: PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CUSTOM should work with VERSION=74.0 - what do the rest of your call parms look like?

Comment: I edited my question to answer yours.

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't mix `PAYMENTREQUEST_0_*` variables and their deprecated counterparts -- use one or the other.  (E.g., don't use `PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION` and `AMT` in the same API call -- either use `PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION` and `PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT`, or use `PAYMENTACTION` and `AMT`.)
2. This appears to be the SetExpressCheckout call.  You can pass a `CUSTOM` value in here, but if you do, the only place it will show up is in the response to your GetExpressCheckoutDetails call.  You need to supply the `CUSTOM` value in your DoExpressCheckoutPayment call in order for it to be recorded to your account.